# Pass parameters to a user control - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this user control:

```
<user:RatingStars runat="server" product="<%= getProductId() %>" category="<%= getCategoryId() %>"></user:RatingStars>
```

You can see that I fill in the product and category by calling two methods:

```
public string getProductId()
{
    return productId.ToString();
}

public string getCategoryId()
{
    return categoryId.ToString();
}
```

I do not understand why, in the user control, when I take the data received (product and category) it gives me "<%= getProductId() %>" instead of giving the id received from that method...

Any help would be kindly appreciated...

**Edit**: Solved with: product='<%# getProductId() %>'

**Last problem**: in the user control I have this:

```
 public string productId;
 public string product
{
    get
    {
        return productId;
    }
    set
    {
        productId = value;
    }
}
```

So, I expect that the productId is set up ok in the user control.
Unfortunately it is null when I try to use it...

Is there anything I wrote that's incorrect?

Comment: Have you tried setting productId to something in say your main method?

Comment: Remember to call `DataBind();` somewhere in the page hosting the control... In `product="<%# something >"`, the # means its a databind expression. It won't actually call `something` until you call 'DataBind()'... Commonly in the `PageLoad()` hosting the control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So that you get compile-time checking, you can give your user control an `ID` and then set its `Product` and `Category` properties in C# like this:

**ASPX:**

```
<user:RatingStars id="myUserControlID" runat="server" Product="<%= getProductId() %>" Category="<%= getCategoryId() %>"></user:RatingStars>
```

**CS:**

```
myUserControlID.Product = GetProductId();
myUserControlID.Category = GetCategoryId();
```

Also, as [5arx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722561/pass-parameters-to-a-user-control-asp-net/5518517#5518517) mentions, once you've populated that then refreshing your page will reload your control and you'll lose the `Product` and `Category` IDs.  You can handle that by using ViewState on the properties in your user control, like this:

```
private const string ProductKey = "ProductViewStateKey";
public string Product
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState[ProductKey] == null)
        {
              // do whatever you want here in case it's null 
              // throw an error, return string.empty or whatever
        }
        return ViewState[ProductKey].ToString();
    }

    set
    {
        ViewState[ProductKey] = value;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I've updated the property name casing to follow convention, as it just makes more sense to me that way!  Personally, I'd always suffix IDs with `ID` (eg: `ProductID`) to distinguish it from a property that contains a `Product` object. Read more about coding standards here: [Are there any suggestions for developing a C# coding standards / best practices document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967/c-coding-standard-best-practices)

Answer (score 1):

Please post some more of your code?

A couple of things:

- `productId` is an object reference (to a `string` object) which means:
- unless you write some intialisation code to 'fill' it with a string reference at the start, it will be `null`.
- if you create a string e.g. `string x = new String()` x will be an *empty string*, which you can think of as "" *without the quotes*. (It *is* a string, but its empty because it has no characters in it).
- you can just write `return productId;` - no need to call `ToString()` on a string.
- Your page does not have an out-of-the-box mechanism to store variables across postbacks. You need to use `ViewState` or hidden form fields to do this.